# Get the value of the previous month and year

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with several columns (`poc_id, user, rw`, among others) and I'm trying to make a query that returns me:

- a column that returns the value of the sum of "points", grouped by month, USER and ID_REW of the past month. If there is no value for the past month, it returns null
- the same but from the same month last year

This would be the output (the input is this same table without the `PREV_MONTH` and `PREV_YEAR` columns, and with another columns that have no relevance to what I'm looking for and I can ignore them):

| USER | ID_REW | POINTS | POC | *DATE* | PREV_MONTH | PREV_YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1635798105611 | 10 | 1 | 01/01/2021 | null | null |
| 1 | 1635798105611 | 20 | 1 | 25/01/2021 | null | null |
| 1 | 1635798105611 | 10 | 1 | 05/02/2021 | 30 | null |
| 1 | 1635798105611 | 15 | 1 | 20/02/2022 | null | 10 |
| 2 | 1641209778245 | 50 | 2 | 03/02/2021 | null | null |
| 2 | 1654058198065 | 60 | 2 | 15/05/2021 | null | null |
| 2 | 1654065920033 | 15 | 2 | 25/02/2022 | null | null |
| 2 | 1654051152555 | 10 | 4 | 26/02/2022 | null | null |
| 2 | 1654051152555 | 5 | 4 | 15/02/2023 | null | 10 |
| 2 | 1635798105611 | 25 | 4 | 25/02/2023 | null | null |

Or:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (USER, ID_REW, POINTS, POC, _DATE_, PREV_MONTH, PREV_YEAR)
VALUES
    (1, 1635798105611, 10, 1, '2021-01-01', NULL, NULL),
    (1, 1635798105611, 20, 1, '2021-01-25', NULL, NULL),
    (1, 1635798105611, 10, 1, '2021-02-05', 30, NULL),
    (1, 1635798105611, 15, 1, '2021-02-20', NULL, 10),
    (2, 1641209778245, 50, 2, '2021-02-03', NULL, NULL),
    (2, 1654058198065, 60, 2, '2021-05-15', NULL, NULL),
    (2, 1654065920033, 15, 2, '2022-02-25', NULL, NULL),
    (2, 1654051152555, 10, 4, '2022-02-26', NULL, NULL),
    (2, 1654051152555, 5, 4, '2023-02-15', NULL, 10),
    (2, 1635798105611, 25, 4, '2023-02-25', NULL, NULL);
```

I tried queries similar to this:

```
WITH cte as 
(
    SELECT
        my columns...,
        ...,
        ....,
        date_buy::date AS _DATE_,
        SUM(POINTS) OVER (PARTITION BY user, id_rew, poc) AS _sum_,
        year(_DATE_)*100 + month(_DATE_) AS ym
    FROM
         etc...
)
SELECT
    USER,
    ID_REW,
    POINTS,
    POC,
    _DATE_,
    LAG(_sum_) OVER (PARTITION BY user, id_rew, poc ORDER BY ym) AS PREV_MONTH,
    LAG(_sum_, 12) OVER (PARTITION BY user, id_rew, poc ORDER BY ym) AS PREV_YEAR
FROM
    cte
GROUP BY
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5;
```

But I have several errors, for example, in year-month 202205 to 202203, it returns the value of 202203 when it should return null (since in 202204 there was no purchase)

I've tried a few things I've seen on the internet (that's where I learned that the LAG function exists) also with some variables, but so far no success trying to replicate what I've seen. Any help is welcome

Comment: Can you share your input data and the output you expect?

Comment: @zedfoxus Input: The same table I put above but without the PREV_MONTH and PREV_YEAR columns. The output would be the column that I put in the post

Comment: @Abra Excuse my ignorance, I'm not sure I understand you: I'm using Snowflake. The column where I take the year from is already embedded in my table in datetime format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to do it with basic JOIN based logic, I included the "current summed month also, just to check the numbers made sense:

```
WITH my_table(USER, ID_REW, POINTS, POC, _DATE_) as (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        (1, 1635798105611, 10, 1, '2021-01-01'::date),
        (1, 1635798105611, 20, 1, '2021-01-25'::date),
        (1, 1635798105611, 10, 1, '2021-02-05'::date),
        (1, 1635798105611, 15, 1, '2021-02-20'::date),
        (2, 1641209778245, 50, 2, '2021-02-03'::date),
        (2, 1654058198065, 60, 2, '2021-05-15'::date),
        (2, 1654065920033, 15, 2, '2022-02-25'::date),
        (2, 1654051152555, 10, 4, '2022-02-26'::date),
        (2, 1654051152555, 5, 4, '2023-02-15'::date),
        (2, 1635798105611, 25, 4, '2023-02-25'::date)
), enriched as (
    select *
        ,date_trunc(month, _date_) as sum_month
    from my_table
), summed as (
    select 
        user 
        ,id_rew
        ,poc
        ,sum_month
        ,dateadd('month', 1, sum_month) as next_month
        ,dateadd('year', 1, sum_month) as next_year
        ,sum(points) as s_points
    from enriched
    group by 1,2,3,4
)
select a.*
    ,b.s_points as current_months_points
    ,c.s_points as prev_months_points
    ,d.s_points as prev_year_points  
from enriched as a
join summed as b 
    on a.user = b.user and a.id_rew = b.id_rew and a.poc = b.poc and a.sum_month = b.sum_month
left join summed as c
    on a.user = c.user and a.id_rew = c.id_rew and a.poc = c.poc and a.sum_month = c.next_month
left join summed as d
    on a.user = d.user and a.id_rew = d.id_rew and a.poc = d.poc and a.sum_month = d.next_year
order by 1,2,4,5
```

[image]

### Performance:

But if it was on my database I would restructure the JOIN's of the prior's to be in a CTE to lower all the costs:

```
WITH my_table(USER, ID_REW, POINTS, POC, _DATE_) as (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        (1, 1635798105611, 10, 1, '2021-01-01'::date),
        (1, 1635798105611, 20, 1, '2021-01-25'::date),
        (1, 1635798105611, 10, 1, '2021-02-05'::date),
        (1, 1635798105611, 15, 1, '2021-02-20'::date),
        (2, 1641209778245, 50, 2, '2021-02-03'::date),
        (2, 1654058198065, 60, 2, '2021-05-15'::date),
        (2, 1654065920033, 15, 2, '2022-02-25'::date),
        (2, 1654051152555, 10, 4, '2022-02-26'::date),
        (2, 1654051152555, 5, 4, '2023-02-15'::date),
        (2, 1635798105611, 25, 4, '2023-02-25'::date)
), enriched as (
    select *
        ,date_trunc(month, _date_) as sum_month
    from my_table
), summed as (
    select 
        user 
        ,id_rew
        ,poc
        ,sum_month
        ,dateadd('month', 1, sum_month) as next_month
        ,dateadd('year', 1, sum_month) as next_year
        ,sum(points) as s_points
    from enriched
    group by 1,2,3,4
), gather as (
    select 
        a.* exclude(next_month, next_year, s_points)
        ,b.s_points as prev_months_points
        ,c.s_points as prev_year_points  
    from summed as a
    left join summed as b 
        on a.user = b.user 
            and a.id_rew = b.id_rew 
            and a.poc = b.poc 
            and a.sum_month = b.next_month
    left join summed as c
        on a.user = c.user 
            and a.id_rew = c.id_rew 
            and a.poc = c.poc 
            and a.sum_month = c.next_year
)
select a.* exclude(sum_month)
    ,b.prev_months_points
    ,b.prev_year_points
from enriched as a
join gather as b 
    on a.user = b.user and a.id_rew = b.id_rew and a.poc = b.poc and a.sum_month = b.sum_month

order by 1,2,4,5
```

[image]